# Filter out empty values from result - xpath query in posgtres

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath

I have an xpath query for extracting data from postgres.

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       xpath('/ns2:path1/ns2:path2/ns3:path3/ns3:path4/ns4:path5/text()', 
             xmlcolumn, 
             ARRAY[
                     ARRAY['ns1', ’namespace1'], 
                     ARRAY['ns3', 'namespace2'], 
                     ARRAY['ns4', 'namespace4']
                  ]) 
from table
```

This gives me result, but when path5 tag value is empty, it prints `{}`
How can we filter out the empty value for the tag?

Comment: Do you mean `path5/text()[normalize-space()]`?

Comment: did not get you, the above query gives me the result like :row1: value1  | value2 |{}. row2: value1 | value2  |{tagvalue}

Comment: I meant that `path5/text()` might return empty nodes while `path5/text()[normalize-space()]` returns non-empty nodes only. Is it not what you want?

Comment: ah, ok, i tried that too, but it still gives empty brackets {}

Comment: XPATH *always* returns an array. `{}` is an empty array, which is what it returns when it doesn't find anything. What do you want it to return when it finds something (do you want it to be in an array), and what do you want when it doesn't find something (or when it's found but empty)?

Comment: ah. yes, thanks @eurotrash, this was the trigger !   had to do btrim to xpath:  btrim(xpath,column::xml)::text, '{}' - this worked